# How destribe database to use Include operation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 table

```
class Table1 { }

class Table2 
{
  ...
  IEnumerable<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
}
```

that linked

```
class Table1To2
{
  int Table1Id { get; set; }
  int Table2Id { get; set; }
}
```

How i can use Table2 `Include` for automatically load Table1s property?
**UPD**
When trying

```
db.Table2s.Include(d => d.Table1s);
```

i have exception
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType `'Models.Table2'` does not declare a navigation property with the name `'Table1s'`.

Comment: So it already loads related entities as part of the query

Comment: are you trying a relationship one to many? many to many? try to follow this link, it will help you http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @bto.rdz  many to many

Answer (score 0):

EF code first does not generate the foreign key for navigation properties that defined as `IEnumerable` and the fluent API does not support `HasMany` for them.
You need to use `ICollection` instead, I could not find MSDN documentation for it, but for lazy-loading navigation there is documentation:

form [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx)

> A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a relationship must return a type that implements ICollection, where T is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.

I tested these two classes:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
}
public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the tables generated for them in the migration(Using EF 6):

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Table1",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Table2",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

And after replacing `IEnumerable` with `Icollection` it generated:

```
   CreateTable(
        "dbo.Table1",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Table2",
         c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
                Table1_Id = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Table1", t => t.Table1_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Table1_Id);
```